# How many kg $ha^-$$^1$ of exchangeable $Mg^2$$^+$ is there in the top 15cm of this field?

Tags: soil, earth-system, soil-moisture, soil-science

Soil testing from a well-drained soil sample in 0-15cm depth of a farmers field provides the following
information:

• Wet weight of a soil sample from a volume of 100 $cm^3$: 200 g

• Moisture content: 20%

• Soil chemical properties (in cmol/kg):

Exchangeable K: 2

Exchangeable Ca : 10

Exchangeable Mg: 4

Exchangeable H: 8

• Molar mass of $H^+$= 1; $Mg^2$$^+$ = 24; $K^+$
 = 39; $Ca^2$+ = 40

1.What is the bulk density of this soil?

in here i did MS=(W-D)/W=0.2=(200-D)/200 SO Dry soil =160, Bulk density =160/100=1.6

2.How many kg $ha^-$$^1$ of exchangeable $Mg^2$$^+$ is there in the top 15cm of this field?

I have no idea about this question

3.What is the percent base saturation?

i dont know hot to get the total CEC in this question